# How to check a radiobutton on button click in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

How can i programmatically check a radiobutton on a button click in Angular?

I have a button like:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-dark">
  Consegna adesso
</button>
```

And two radio buttons like:

```
        <div class="form-check">
          <input
            class="form-check-input"
            type="radio"
            name="radioQuando"
            id="radioOra"
            value="ora"
            checked
          />
          <label class="form-check-label" for="radioOra" ngModel>
            Ora <span class="text-muted">(Arrivo tra 20-40 min)</span>
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input
            class="form-check-input"
            type="radio"
            name="radioQuando"
            id="radioProgramma"
            value="programma"
            (click)="open(programma)"
          />
          <label class="form-check-label" for="radioProgramma">
            Programma
          </label>
        </div>
```

How can i check the radio `#radioOra` when the button is pressed?

Answer (score 2):

You can add click event on button

```
<button type="button" (click)="onClick(true)" class="btn btn-block btn-dark">
   Consegna adesso
</button>
```

component

```
checked = false

onClick(val) {
 this.checked = val
}
```

In template

```
<input
        class="form-check-input"
        type="radio"
        name="radioQuando"
        id="radioOra"
        value="ora"
        [checked]="checked" // notice checked here
      />
```

To re-checked button after clicking to `radioProgramma` radio buttion

```
<input
        class="form-check-input"
        type="radio"
        name="radioQuando"
        id="radioProgramma"
        value="programma"
        (click)="onClicked(false)"
      />
```

If you are working with reactive form you can set checked value if the radioOra has value.

Working [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qjl4ce)

Hope this solve you problem

Comment: i think you didn't noticed that it's a radio button (means that you should use something like : `[checked]="checked == 'ora'"`)

Comment: Read the last line of the question `How can i check the radio #radioOra when the button is pressed?` so when button clicked radioOra needs to be checked and this is what my solution serves that purpose

Comment: yeah that's works. just wanted to suggest a cleaner way to bind data to radio buttons. (ps: your stackblitz works only on first time. it doesn't work when you press the button for second time.)

Comment: @yaya what should happen when user press second time?

Comment: the problem is : when user selects the second option manually, and then presses the button, it won't select the first option anymore. (because second input is checked by user, and first input is checked programmatically. so both are checked at the same time.)

Comment: @yaya updated my answer now it addressed that use case.

Comment: i think it's better to bind the `checked` as `ngModel`

Comment: @yash could you make an example with ngModel? as by using Kamran solution as you said when i click on the second radio which has been checked opens a model, then from that modal i can press the button which set checked to other radio but as the second has been set by user is not heppening